# Finding many occurrences of custom built shortcode in String

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, shortcode

I'm building a quiz based system, and users can generate question types by entering something similar to a shortcode into the text area.  The plan is to be able to convert the shortcodes into HTML.

Here is an example of how users might write inside the text area:

> Here's a question
>
> What is your name?  [question type="text" question-answers="Mike|mike|Michael"]
>
> Male or Female?  [question type="radio" question-answers="Male" possible-answers="Male|Female" name="sex"]
>
> How many cars do you own  [question type="checkbox" question-answers="2" possible-answers="1|2|3|4" name="cars"]

The users add the 'shortcodes' via a click of a button, and are given the options to add values to the attributes e.g question-answers etc... this saves them writing any 'code'.

What I want to do is on submit (in the background),  convert all the shortcodes into html inputs. The actual converting won't be a problem, what I am having a problem with is finding the occurrences of all the shortcodes.

I have tried using:

```
preg_match_all(SOME_REG_EX, $question, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

but I'm not getting anything useful, probably due to my regular expression being incorrect,  I have tried various regex's but not had any luck.

Comment: Managed to find the regular expression that I needed to find each occurrence it was:  `'/\[[^\[]*question[^\]]*\]/'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the regular expression that I needed to find each occurrence it was:

`'/\[[^\[]*question[^\]]*\]/'`

Which gets the whole `[question OTHER_ATTRIBUTES]` shortcode